# Find first duplicate line in a file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to find the **first** duplicate line in a text file.

The way I usually find duplicate lines in a file is by using uniq, which takes a sorted file, so I:

```
sort inputfile | uniq -c | sort -nr > outputfile
```

to count all the duplicates and print in decreasing order.

By sorting then using uniq, I lose when/where in the original that duplicate occurs, and I am only now interested in what line is the first duplicate.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
awk '{ if(seen[$0]) { print; exit } seen[$0] = 1 }' file
```

This will keep track of each line and then print the first one it's seen before. If you want the line number, print NR as well.

```
awk '{ if(seen[$0]) { print NR, $0; exit } seen[$0] = 1 }' file
```

Comment: You can golf that down: `awk 's[$0]++ {print;exit}' file` -- that uses post-increment, so it is true the first repetition of a line.

Comment: I don't think it is correct: `cat -n f | sort -k2 -k1,1 | uniq -df1` returns the *first* line number that *has* a duplicate, not the 2nd time it is seen. You can't even do `sort -k2 -k1,1r` because, if there are more than 2 times the line appears, it will give you the *last* line number.

Answer (score 1):

Since I know Perl, I tend to use it for one-liners:

```
perl -e 'foreach (<>) { $n++; if ($l{$_}++) { print "$n\n"; last; } }' < infile
```

This prints to STDOUT the line number of the first duplicate.

Comment: Or shorter: `perl -ne 'die $_ if $seen{$_}; $seen{$_}++' infile`

Comment: Nice, except that doesn't show the line number and `die` writes to STDERR.

Comment: True. Even shorter, including line number and STDOUT: `perl -ne 'die "$. $_" if $seen{$_}++' infile 2>&1`